# Вопрос по шаблону instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, bootstrap, instagram

Был установлен и настроен Instafeed.js
Требуется вывод фотографий по определенному тэгу. Вот что требуется:
[image: Что требуется]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    userId: 11325936,
    tagName: 'beerhouse',
    limit: 3,
    accessToken: '11325936.467ede5.0a8e441bf48f4f1f804126bdd155bf50',
    template: '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 liders"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>'
  });
  userFeed.run();
</script>
```

На данный момент все фотографии выводятся в лидерах, хотя требуется три фотографии отображать в лидерах, а остальные под заголовком "Ещё". Как можно разбить их на группы? Менять шаблон или вставлять второй скрипт?